# the positioning mechanism in bisonc++ YYLTYPE is always returning 0

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, grammar, bison, bisonc++

While parsing source file using grammar by bisonc++, I want to get line number of token. For this I've enabled `%lsp-needed`. Now when I'm accessing the line number using `@1.first_line` and `@1.last_line`, both are printing 0 even though the tokens are not from 0th line.